# Eclipse formatter alternates format each time (and won't split a line)

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

Eclipse is formatting code one way and then another, flipping particular bits of code backwards and forwards alternately each time it's used.

What have I done wrong here?

Here is the first state:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    String dir = System.getenv(EtlConstants.ENVVAR_PROPERTIES_DIR);
    if (dir != null
        && ("\\".equals(dir.charAt(dir.length() - 2)) || "/".equals(dir.charAt(dir.length() - 2)))) {
        dir = dir.substring(0, dir.length() - 1);
    }
}
```

and this alternates with this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    String dir = System.getenv(EtlConstants.ENVVAR_PROPERTIES_DIR);
    if (dir != null
            && ("\\".equals(dir.charAt(dir.length() - 2)) || "/".equals(dir.charAt(dir.length() - 2)))) {
        dir = dir.substring(0, dir.length() - 1);
    }
}
```

The difference is the tab in the second line of the if statement.

I am trying to get the formatter to wrap the same line at the `||` as well but I can't work out why it's flipping between these two states. It's obviously the interaction of two separate rules, but which?

EDIT: This is with Eclipse Luna 4.4.0.

EDIT 2: I am using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> because I have set Eclipse to do a format on save. It is obviously one of the other Save actions that is causing the format to change:

- format all lines
- organise imports
- convert control statement bodies to block
- add final modifier to private fields
- add final modifier to method parameters
- add missing '@Override' annotations
- add missing '@Override' annotations to implementations of interface methods
- add missing '@Deprecated' annotations
- remove unnecessary casts
- remove trailing white spaces on all lines
- correct indentation

EDIT 3: I just removed the last Save action and it no longer causes that line to jump backwards and forwards.

So thanks to all you people invoking the formatter with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> - that switched a light on because I realised I was using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> all the time.

Comment: Can not reproduce. For me, it indents the `&&` as in the second code, but also splits the long line (at the 2nd `charAt`, not at the `||`, and with two more tabs), and then it stays this way. IMHO, it looks horrible. I only use auto-format to fix totally screwed up code.

Comment: Can't reproduce in Eclipse Kepler SR1. Check in Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter > Edit... > Line Wrapping > *Default indentation for wrapped lines* and *Never join already wrapped lines* and *Prefer wrapping outer expressions*

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @tobias_k (sorry, I can't comment). After <kbd>CRTL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. It looks like:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    String dir = System.getenv(EtlConstants.ENVVAR_PROPERTIES_DIR);
    if (dir != null
            && ("\\".equals(dir.charAt(dir.length() - 2)) || "/".equals(dir
                    .charAt(dir.length() - 2)))) {
        dir = dir.substring(0, dir.length() - 1);
    }
}
```

In `eclipse`, formatting options are under Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter. Show the profile you are using and try to modify `Line Wrapping` tab. Not sure, but I guess you'd want to modify `Binary Expressions`.

**UPDATE:**

Don't know about Luna. I usually work on eclipse 3.2 (Callisto) or eclipse 3.6 (Helios). Both versions admit edit a formatting profile.

**Remark:** Is not allowed to modify a built-in profile. Create a new, based on a certain built-in profile, and then, modify that one.

I show in Helios:

[image: Edit Profile]

Click on Edit, and you'll see a way to modify:

[image: Tags]

Nevertheless. It's not easy at all. I'm not able to get what you want automatically. Well, as commented above by @tobias_k, I never use it, either. Unless code is really terrible. I always prefer to format by myself.

Comment: How do you want to see the profile? The XML export is huge, and the screenshot doesn't show anything except the currently selected option. Anyway, I have `Never join already wrapped lines` off, `Prefer wrapping outer expressions` on, and `Binary expressions` are set to wrap where necessary, wrap before operator, and indent by one.

Comment: @Adam, I updated the answer. However, is not easy to get what you want.

Comment: sorry but I can't see those images - I assume they are images. I just spent an hour comparing the 'built-in' config with my own and I couldn't find anything that changed it.

Comment: Yes, they are two images. However, there are a lot of options and cases, I try to get what you want, but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the primary question is that the Eclipse formatter is doing one thing to the code and then the Eclipse 'on save' actions are doing something else which essentially undo the formatting.